# Changing my name upon conversion

Tags: naming

I am considering converting to Islam, and I have a question. I understand that upon conversion you need to change your name if it expresses a concept that goes against Islam.

My name is Ryan Bruhl, and according to some research I've done online the name Ryan means "little king". Some of my Muslim friends have suggested that that intonation (that I'm a king of some sort) not good since it might imply I'm "above" Allah and that I should change it. What should I do?

Secondly, what would my name be once I change it? [This site](http://www.muslimconverts.com/muslimnames/how-a-convert-changes-name.htm) says that the formula is `<chosen name> ibn-<fathers name>`:

```
If you are Male and you have decided you like a certian name. Then your full name will be as follows:

Chosen name ibn-fathers name
Let us assume that Bilal is a name which you have chosen for your self and your fathers name is John Smith. Then your full name will be 
Bilal ibn John 
which means Bilal son of John.
```

Let's say I were to take the name Fadil. Since my father's name is Daniel, would my name then be Fadil ibn-Daniel?

Thank you!

Comment: I was wondering if renaming is really necessary. I know that our Messenger (pbuh) renamed some people because they had bad names.

Comment: Well, do you think that my name (Ryan) is a bad name? Does it go against Islam for the reasons I said above (or any other reason)?

Comment: @RyanBruhl Its better for you to visit a nearby Mosque and try to ask for a  scholar so he could explain you in a better way as Scholars are knowledgeable people about Islam and can inform you about every enquiries as you have also asked about beard etc.Here you might or might not get the actual ruling of Islam.Congratulations for your convertion in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not required anywhere in Quran for you to change your name.   There are some narratives associated to the Messenger saying he changed names of certain people, however, those names were related to bad things.

Ryan is also an Arabic name, meaning "boy," and in Persian it means "wise"

Even if it meant "little king" it's not referring you as god.

You can choose a nickname for yourself if you like.  Ryan aka (arabic accent) rrrryaan

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would I keep my last name as is? Or would I change it to my father's name, ie Ryan Daniel? Or change my middle name so that it's Ryan Daniel Bruhl?

Comment: Using your father's first name is Arab culture and not Islam.  You can keep your family name.  None of it is a requirement in Islam, the Quran is flexible in allowing a person what to do, as long as your identity won't be lost.

Comment: In that link I posted, it says that "it is essential that one attributes his or her lineage to his or her biological  father. by having their second name as son of so and so and daughter of so and so". That person seems knowledgeable, how come that advice does not apply to me?

Comment: Knowledgeable doesn't mean wise.  Wisdom is in understanding and application.  If you intentionally deny your real father and claim to be from another is quite different from changing your actual name to a Arab name.  Changing your real name to a fake name would be more of a sin.

Comment: So as long as I have the same last name as my father, it's fine?

Comment: Yes, it's your family name from your father.

Comment: So if I were adopted or something, in that case I would have to change it?

Comment: If you know your real fathers' name, then yes you would.  if you don't, then you'd continue with what you have.

Comment: Should I adopt an Islamic nickname or something? Like I keep my current name, but have a different name I use with my Muslim friends?

Comment: There is no such thing as an Islamic name. I think you mean Arab names.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. I'm just wondering what you opinion is on that.

Comment: You can tell people your real name and then say "you can call me Fadil" if you like.  it's up to you really, no pressure.  A lot of Muslims say unnecessary things as religion when they're not.  Names are one of them.  So it's up to you.